# Power BI-Compare 2 Text columns for equality using a measure

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, dax

Data is similar to below:

[image]

OLD_ZEND comes from table1 and NEW_ZEND comes from table2. Looking to create a measure that will compare the strings of OLD_ZEND and NEW_ZEND and if they are the same output Y else output N.

Comment: Do you need to compare the same row in both tables? Do both tables have the same number of rows? Is there a common column between both tables?

Comment: Same row in both tables. Both tables have the same number of rows. There is a common column which forms a one to many relationship.

Comment: If the relationship is one to many the common column doesn't help in this case, you need a common column that relate each row in both tables. If you can create a row number column in both tables you can logically relate row by row in both tables. Also this kind of calculations are better performed in a calculated column instead of a measure since measure is calculated depending on the context while columns are calculated at the row context (like you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a calculated column in one of your tables.

Create an `index` column in each table by right clicking `table1` and select `Edit Query`, the `Query Editor` will be opened, in the `Add Column` tab select `Index Column - From 1` then press `Close & Apply`. Do the same for the `table2`.

Then create a new calculated column in the `table2`, call it `OLD_ZEND` and use this DAX expression:

```
OLD_ZEND =
    IF (
        [NEW_ZEND] = LOOKUPVALUE ( table1[OLD_ZEND], table1[Index], [Index] ),
        "Y",
        "N"
    )
```

Now you have a new column in `table2` with `Y` or `N` depending if `OLD_ZEND` and `NEW_ZEND` are equal.

Let me know if this helps.